# How to fix memory exhausted issue while creating only S3 object pre-signed URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, memory, out-of-memory

I generate signed URL of images stored on S3 (using AWS PHP SDK) in my website built in PHP. I get 500 error when I try to generate signed URL for more than 40 images but by clicking on "Reload", it loads all images.
After investigation, I found out the following errors are causing 500 error.

```
Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in  /vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/data/s3/2006-03-01/api-2.json.php on line 3

Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in  /system/core/Exceptions.php on line 1
```

Code to generate pre signed URL

```
$s3 = new S3Client([
                'region'  => 'region',
                'version' => 'latest',
                'credentials' => [
                    'key'    => "myKey",
                    'secret' => "Secret here"
                ]
            ]);
            $cmd = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Key' => $keyname
            ]);
            
             
            $request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+30 minutes');
            $presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();
```

On different forums, It is suggested that memory size should be at least 128 MB these days. I will increase the size but my concern is that I only get signed URL of images then how it make the memory exhausted. Is there any better way to fix this.

Comment: Creating a pre-signed URL should not involve much memory. It actually just does some Base64 conversion and creates a hash. Not very intensive at all. By the way, you should avoid putting your credentials in code files -- instead, use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to create a config file and the AWS SDK will automatically use it.

Comment: Other operation must be consuming the memory, look that your AWS SDK is only trying to allocate ~20Kb. As John said, this is not the problem. Maybe you are fetching the images before trying to presign the URL?